# Hiding the MainActivty's placeholder when a new fragment appears on top of it

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is inside the LinearLayout of my activtiy_main.xml. It contains an emply frame layout and a button outside the frame.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    **android:id="@+id/placeholder"**
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is my fragment1.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<TextView android:text="Hello Sir"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> </LinearLayout>
```

I have successfully created a java file named hello for this fragment.

And lastly this is my MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button change ,  change2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new hello();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                   R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                    R.animator.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                    R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit);
            ft.replace(R.id.placeholder, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }
    });


}
```

}

This executes fine but the problem is the FrameLayout(from the activtiy_main.xml) stays even after the fragment appears on top of it.

[Screen Shot after the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1t2R.png)

I want to make the frameLayout(id - placeholder) to disappear or hide after the fragment has come on top of it.

Please help me.

P.S: This just a test application. Can't share the original one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep mainActivity as place holder

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Add one fragment_one with button in activity and replace fragment_one with fragment_two it will work fine.

fragment_one

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> </LinearLayout>
```

fragment_two

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:text="Hello Sir"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not working.
I want to hide the placeholder after the fragment_one appears
With your method nothing changes
Are you getting the question ?